# Setting a variable based on the time of day

Tags: cmd.exe, shell-script, time, date-time

I cannot seem to get the **if %day% EQU** lines correct. I am trying to get the **autoShutDown** variable to "T" when the script is run between Friday night 8:30 PM and Saturday at 5:15 PM. But it seems like sometimes the formatting is different and causes the variable assignment to not work correctly.

What's the best way to set the variable?
In case it makes a difference, I have Windows 8.1.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET day=%date:~0,3%
SET time=%time:~0%
set "time=%time: =%"
set currentDate=%date:~4,10%
set autoShutDown=F

if %day% EQU Fri IF %time% GEQ 20:30:00.00 set autoShutDown=T
if %day% EQU Sat IF %time% LEQ 17:15:00.00 set autoShutDown=T 

if "%autoShutDown%"=="T" (
    GOTO AUTOSHUTDOWN
)

GOTO WEEKDAY

:AUTOSHUTDOWN
%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\SHUTDOWN.EXE /s /t 180 /c "Shutdown in 180 seconds" /d p:4:1

:WEEKDAY
```

[ EDIT ]
So based on what @harrymc wrote below, is the following what I should be doing?

```
@ECHO OFF
set autoShutDown=F

for /f %%C in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get dayofweek^,Year^,Month^,Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Second /Format:List 2^>nul ^| find "="') do @set current%%C

REM - Friday 8 PM or later
if %currentDayOfWeek% EQU 5 IF %currentHour% GEQ 20 set autoShutDown=T

REM - ...or Saturday earlier than 6 PM
if %currentDayOfWeek% EQU 6 IF %currentHour% LEQ 17 set autoShutDown=T

if "%autoShutDown%"=="T" (
    GOTO AUTOSHUTDOWN
)

GOTO WEEKDAY

:AUTOSHUTDOWN
%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\SHUTDOWN.EXE /s /t 180 /c "Shutdown in 180 seconds" /d p:4:1

:WEEKDAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%DATE%` is not dependable, because its format is customizable and can change
per each user.

This code, meant to run inside a `.bat` file, will extract all the
date and time parameters using the 
[wmic command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmic):

```
@echo off

for /f %%C in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get dayofweek^,Year^,Month^,Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Second /Format:List 2^>nul ^| find "="') do @set current%%C

:display the variables
set current
```

This is what it did on Sunday:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I added something onto my original post, since it was completely unreadable in a comment here. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's the way it can be used.

Comment: If this answer helped solve your problem, you might consider accepting it.